# Should karma.conf.js always be located at the route of the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm used to building ng applications using just Angular and with this typical structure:

```
app
    js
          home
              home.controller.js
              home.directive.js
          shared
              usedByAll.controller.js
              usedByAll.directive.js
    templates
         home.html
test
    e2e
       protractor tests
node_modules
index.html
package.json
```

So that when someone else coming in wants to catch up they just need to run

```
npm install
```

to install all the dependencies listed into their node_modules folder saving them time.

But recently I've started working on a Ruby-on-Rails project that is looking to angularize some of its components. This naturally means they're following their own MVC style and project structure and the angular stuff has been restricted to the following folders:

```
app/assets/javascripts/angular-components/component1
                                          component2
                                          component3
                                          lib/angular.js
                                              angular-mocks.js
                                              etc
```

This is fine for development but when it comes down to testing I think this could be a problem. So my questions are really the following:

1 - When installing new modules via **npm** and attempting to save them as devDependencies 
    npm install karma --save-dev 
to the package.json file, doesn't it mean you should have the node_modules folder at the root as well as the package.json file at the root?

2 - Should the karma.conf.js file, like the node_modules folder and package.json file, always be at the absolute root of the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many rails/angular applications you can see that Angular is tucked away inside the app/assets/javascripts folder. I personally don't like mixing and matching what I'm using when it comes to pages - i.e. go and get a Rails generated view or this one is an Angular one so go there.

Instead I broke out the two. Essentially the Rails part of this just functions as an API whereas Angular now handles the front end entirely. This allows you to treat the angular part nearly as a standalone app, following the typical angular structure. By doing this you can have the karma.conf.js file at the root of this folder.

```
ExampleAppName
    - app (All Angular stuff is in here)
         - src
         - gulpfile.js
         - karma.conf.js
         - package.json
    - api (All rails stuff is in here)
         - rails stuff
```